# How to create a trigger to ( to data factory or azure function or databricks ) when there are 500 new files land in a azure storage blob

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

I have a azure storage container where I will be getting many files on daily basis.My requirement is that I need a trigger in azure data factory or databricks when each time 500 new files are arrived so I can process them.
In Datafatory we have event trigger which will trigger for each new files(with filename and path). but is it possible to get multiple new files and their details at same time?
What services in azure I can use for this scenario.. event hub? azure function.. queues?

Answer (score 0):

One of the characteristics of a serverless architecture is to execute something whenever a new event occurs. Based on that, you can't use those services alone.

Here's what I would do:

#1 Azure Functions with Blob Trigger, to execute whenever a new file arrives. This would not start the processing of the file, but just 'increment' the count of files that would be stored on Cosmos DB.

#2 Azure Cosmos DB, also offers a Change Feed, which is like an event sourcing whenever something changes in a collection. As the document  created / modified on #1 will hold the count, you can use another Azure Function #3 to consume the  change feed.

#3 This function will just contain an if statement which will "monitor" the current count, and if it's above the threshold, start the processing.

After that, you just need to update the document and reset the count.